# How can I query concrete Elasticsearch record by its __id?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

1. I have Elastic with Nest.
2. I have logs in elastic. I have no problems to query all by `.client.Query(...` But I'm having problems in getting one specific document by its __id using `client.Get`.

I'm using:

`_el_client.Get<SystemLog>(id); // This does not work (_id = QUrLVXgB1uALlflB_-oF)`

But object / record is not returned... What is the way to query a concrete elastic `_id` from Nest client?

This is the beginning of the document (just for the info).

```
 "_index": "webapi-development-2021-03",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "QUrLVXgB1uALlflB_-oF",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2021-03-21T18:18:55.2173785+01:00",
    "level": "Information",
    "messageTemplate": "{HostingRequestFinishedLog:l}",
    // etc., etc.
```

Thx for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Ok after many tests I find out solutions... I must say official DOCS sucks... This should be as startup examples.. Most common needs..

1. When using Get I need to specific concrete index not only part ending with `*`

Example:

```
 GetResponse<SystemLog> result = _el_client.Get<SystemLog>(request.id, idx => idx.Index("webapi-development-2021-03"));
```

- Require to build id for app containing __id + __index

2. Using search (easier but slower)

```
var response = _el_client.Search<SystemLog>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
       .Ids(i => i
          .Values(request.id)
          )
       )
     );
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out, must say that this example is present in their github readme: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#getting-a-document